# Comparing an URL to a given list of URL schemes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I would like to check if a given URL matches a list of URL schemes. I have come this far:

```
function on_wikipedia() {
    // the list of allowed locations
    var allowed_locations = new Array( "http://*.wikibooks.org/*"
                                     , "http://*.wikimedia.org/*"
                                     , "http://*.wikipedia.org/*"
                                     , "http://*.wikiquote.org/*"
                                     , "http://*.wikiversity.org/*"
                                     , "http://*.wiktionary.org/*"
                                     , "http://www.mediawiki.org/*"
                                     , "https://secure.wikimedia.org/*"
                                     );

    // current location; e.g. "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
    var current_location = content.document.location;

    var valid = false;

    // compare current_location to allowed_locations and set valid to true,
    // if it matches
    //
    // FIXME

    return valid;
}
```

Maybe it is a bad idea to do it like this. Maybe I should use regular expressions to make the comparason? Unfortunately I'm lost... I have no JavaScript experience at all. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that it is better in just about every way to use `var foo = [ ... ];` instead of `var foo = new Array( ... );` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onWikipedia(){
  // Untested
  var allowedLocations = /^(?:http:\/\/(?:.+?\.wik(?:ibooks|imedia|ipedia|iquote|iversity|tionary)\.org|www\.mediawiki\.org)\/|https:\/\/secure.wikimedia.org\/)/i;
  return allowedLocations.test( content.document.location );
}
```

The `i` at the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive. Remove if you don't want that.

In general, the regex says this:

- Starting at the front of the string (`^`), look for either of the following (`(?:...|...)`):

  - `http://` followed by either of the following, and then a literal slash (`\/`)

    - basically anything (`.+?`) followed by a literal period (`\.`) followed by `wik` and then...oh, one of these domain names, followed by `.org`, or
    - `www.mediawiki.org`
  - `https://secure.wikimedia.org/`

Note that the very permissive `.+?` allows something like `http://foo.bar.com/?.wikibooks.org/` to be matched. You probably want something more restrictive, such as letters, numbers, underscores, periods, or hyphens. If so, replace `.+?` with `[\w.-]+?`

Alternatively, instead of testing against the entire URL, you might want to just check against the hostname:

```
function onWikipedia(){
  if (location.protocol=='https:'){
    return location.hostname == 'secure.wikimedia.org';
  }else{
    var regexp = /^(?:www\.wikimedia|.+?\.wik(?:ibooks|imedia|ipedia|iquote|iversity|tionary)\.org/i;
    return regexp.test( location.hostname );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution works. I couldn't get the second one working though.